# How to convert a string into an arbitrary length integer

Tags: c++, c, binary, numerical-methods

I'm working on a project to implement multi-precision arithmetic in C++. I've sort of fallen at the first hurdle. I'm trying to convert a c-string into the binary representation of an integer that will probably contain more bits than an int can hold (this may be an arbitrary number of bits in theory). I essentially want to create an array of longs that will hold the binary representation of the number contained in the string, with index 0 being the least significant "limb" of the number. I am assuming that the number is in base ten.

I have already looked into using code from GMP but it is needlessly complex for my needs and has huge amounts of platform dependent code.

Any help would be great! If you require more details let me know.

Comment: I think you're trying to hurdle the wrong hurdle first. Implement the arithmetic, then use that to help convert from a base 10 string to your internal representation. It's a fairly obvious sequence of multiplications and additions, at least until you start optimizing.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for the comment, the reason I haven't done this fist is because the operations are going to be GPU accelerated, which presents a whole host of issues. I know it is possible to implement the conversion first as GMP does it.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel.  Use GMP.  All the GMP platform dependent code is only used if it applies to your configuration.

Comment: @brianbeuning: "Use GMP" -- depending on environment. Unfortunately GMP cannot recover from running out of memory. This might be fine in environments where programs are never expected to recover from running out of memory, and it may even be a significant optimization. It makes the GMP interface unusable in certain environments, though.

Comment: @brianbeuning I think you've missed the point of this a little, I'm creating a GPU accelerated multi-precision library, it should perform around x10 better than GMP when it's finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @SteveJessop said

```
class Number {
public:
    Number();
    void FromString( const char * );
    void operator *= ( int );
    void operator += ( int );
    void operator = ( int );
}

Number::FromString( const char * string )
{
    *this = 0;
    while( *string != '\0' ) {
        *this *= 10;
        *this += *string - '0';
        string++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion that this is the simplest approach for now, I know there is a more efficient solution and I'll post it here if/when I find it.

Comment: One way to make it faster is to convert 9 chars to an int, and then fold the int into the Number.  Once there are less then 9 digits left then switch to the above code.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want to do is have a working test engine.  This is a brain-dead, easy to understand, arbitrary precision arithmetic engine.

The purpose of this engine is a few fold.  First, it makes converting strings into arbitrary precision integers really easy.  Second, it is a means to test your later, improved engines.  Even if it is really slow, you'll be more convinced it is correct (and having two independent implementations means corner case errors in one might be caught in another, even if you aren't more confident in either).

Assumes `short` is at least 16 bits and `char` is at least 8 (use the actual `int_8` style types if your compiler supports them)

```
short Add(unsigned char left, unsigned char right, unsigned char extra=0) { return unsigned short(left)+unsigned short(right)+unsigned short(extra); }
unsigned short Multiply(unsigned char left, unsigned char right) { return unsigned short(left)*unsigned short(right); }
std::pair<unsigned char,unsigned char> CarryCalc(unsigned short input) {
  std::pair<unsigned char,unsigned char> retval;
  retval.first = input & (1<<8-1);
  retval.second = input>>8;
  return retval;
}
struct BigNum {
  std::vector<char> base256;
  BigNum& operator+=( BigNum const& right ) {
    if (right.base256.size() > base256.size())
      base256.resize(right.base256.size());
    auto lhs = base256.begin();
    auto rhs = right.base256.begin();
    char carry = 0;
    for(; rhs != right.base256.end(); ++rhs, ++lhs) {
      auto result = CarryCalc( Add( *lhs, *rhs, carry ) );
      *lhs = result.first;
      carry = result.second;
    }
    while( carry && lhs != base256.end() ) {
      auto result = CarryCalc( Add( *lhs, 0, carry ) );
      *lhs = result.first;
      carry = result.second;
    }
    if (carry)
      base256.push_back(carry);
    return *this;
  }
  BigNum& scaleByChar( unsigned char right ) {
    char carry = 0;
    for(auto lhs = base256.begin(); lhs != base256.end(); ++lhs) {
      unsigned short product = Multiply( *lhs, right );
      product += carry;
      auto result = CarryCalc( product );
      *lhs = result.first;
      carry = result.second;
    }
    if (carry)
      base256.push_back(carry);        
    return *this;
  }
  BigNum& shiftRightBy8BitsTimes( unsigned int x ) {
    if (x > base256.size()) {
      base256.clear();
      return *this;
    }
    base256.erase( base256.begin(), base256.begin()+x) )
    return *this;
  }
  // very slow, O(x * n) -- should be O(n) at worst
  BigNum& shiftLeftBy8BitsTimes( unsigned int x ) {
    while( x != 0 ) {
      base256.insert( base256.begin(), 0 );
      --x;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  // very slow, like O(n^3) or worse (should be O(n^2) at worst, fix shiftLeft)
  BigNum& operator*=( BigNum const& right ) {
    unsigned int digit = 0;
    BigNum retval;
    while (digit < right.base256.size()) {
      BigNum tmp = *this;
      tmp.shiftLeftBy8BitsTimes( digit );
      tmp.scaleByChar( right.base256[digit] );
      retval += tmp;
      ++digit;
    }
    *this = retval;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

which is a quick and dirty arbitrary precision integer type (not even compiled yet) with horrible performance.  Test something like the above, convince yourself it is solid, then build up from there.

Much of your code could take the actual BigNum class in question as a template argument, so you can do the same algorithm with two different implementations, and compare the results for testing purposes.

Oh, and another piece of advice -- write a template class that "improves" a bare-bones arbitrary precision library via CRTP.  The goal is to only have to write `*=`, `+=`, `unary -`, and maybe `/=` and some `shift_helper` and `compare_helper` functions, and have the rest of your methods automatically written for you by the template.  By putting the boilerplate in one spot it makes it easier to maintain more than one version of your `BigNum` class: and having more than one version is very important for testing purposes.